# flask-admin: How to get current user's other info(besides id, name, email)?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I want the user's name and his team are stored automatically when creating a project. The classes are defined below:

```
class Team(db.Model, RoleMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.name  

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(255))
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(255))
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)
    teams = db.relationship('Team', secondary=teams_users,uselist=False,
                        backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))

    def __str__(self):
       return self.first_name

 class Project(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    team = db.Column(db.Unicode(64))
    developer = db.Column(db.Unicode(128))  

       def __unicode__(self):
          return self.developer
```

And I use the following to store the current user's first name and team when a project is created:

```
     class ProjectView(sqla.ModelView):
        def on_model_change(self, form, model, is_created):
           if is_created:
             model.developer = current_user.first_name
             model.team = current_user.teams
```

the user name is correctly saved but the teams was failed to saved. I've also tried to store `model.team =current_user.email` , `model.team =current_user.last_name` and `model.team =current_user.id`and all worked. Not sure what happened why failed to store `current_user.teams`. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because `User.teams` is a not a `db.Column`, like `Project.team` and the other fields, its a `db.relationship`, if you want to assign a value to it, it has to be an instance of `Team`

so you would have to do something like:

```
class ProjectView(sqla.ModelView):
    def on_model_change(self, form, model, is_created):
        if is_created:
            model.developer = current_user.first_name
            model.team = Team(name=current_user.teams)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but an error occured: `Failed to create record. (sqlite3.InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type. [SQL: u'UPDATE project SET teams=? WHERE project.id = ?'] [parameters: (<__main__.Team object at 0x0000000004C3FC18>, 23)]`

Comment: oh yea, because model.team is `Unicode`, so you can set `model.team` to the teams name  `model.team = current_user.teams.name`

Comment: Now it works using `model.team = current_user.teams.name`, thanks.